# How can I create a style with borders from VSTO code?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am developing an Excel addin in C#, using VSTO. In this addin, I create some styles and add them to the current workbook. Everything works fine until I try to set some borders on my style.

This is the code I use:

```
var style = workbook.styles.Add("My style");

style.IncludeAlignment = false;
style.IncludeFont = false;
style.IncludeNumber = false;
style.IncludeProtection = false;
style.IncludePatterns = false;

style.IncludeBorder = true;
foreach (XlBordersIndex borderIndex in new[] { 
                XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft, 
                XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight, 
                XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop, 
                XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom })
{
    style.Borders[borderIndex].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
}
```

I would expect this code to create a style with the four borders set, but it seems that only the left edge is set (I can see that by looking at the style object from the debugger after the loop, and in Excel by editing "My style").

I tried recording a VBA macro to see the code generated by Excel and I obtained this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add Name:="My style"
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("My style")
    .IncludeNumber = False
    .IncludeFont = False
    .IncludeAlignment = False
    .IncludeBorder = True
    .IncludePatterns = False
    .IncludeProtection = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("My style").Borders(xlLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("My style").Borders(xlRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("My style").Borders(xlTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles("My style").Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

This macro works as expected. I noticed that it uses `xlTop`, `xlLeft`, etc. instead of `xlEdgeTop`, `xlEdgeLeft`, but I can't find any documentation about these constants and they are not available in the VSTO enumeration `XlBordersIndex`. From what I found, it seems that the latter represents the edge of the range, while the former represents the edge of each cell, but I'm not sure about this and I think the difference does not make much sense when talking about styles, which applies to a single cell AFAICT.

Why do I have a different behavior between my C# addin and this VBA macro? How can I create a style with borders from my VSTO code?

Comment: I just found this question, which seems to talk about the same issue: [Excel range Style: specifying Borders via VSTO doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13827369/20984).

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants.aspx


xlBottom = -4107
xlLeft = -4131
xlRight = -4152
xlTop = -4160

Comment: Do you have to process all the borders?  I use this method with just VBA to get a border around a cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121425/border-around-each-cell-in-a-range/13130220#13130220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/excel-style-object-border-problems.2783145/), it seems that there is a difference between the borders of a style and the borders of a range: the latter are indexed by [`XlBordersIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlbordersindex.aspx) (`xlEdgeTop`, `xlEdgeLeft`,...), as stated in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.borders.aspx), but the former are indexed by [`Constants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants.aspx) (`xlTop`, `xlLeft`,...).

This can make sense if we consider that a style applies to individual cells and not to a range, but this also means that to access a style borders, we must bypass the interface of the `Borders` interface using unrelated constants. This workaround, proposed by AnushRudaa [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/c41b4d8d-31a5-4960-b22c-0e11ac02212d/#2b0798dc-05fc-4caf-8c6a-301e1e9c4af3), seems to work:

```
foreach (XlBordersIndex borderIndex in new[] { 
                (XlBordersIndex)Constants.xlLeft, 
                (XlBordersIndex)Constants.xlRight, 
                (XlBordersIndex)Constants.xlTop, 
                (XlBordersIndex)Constants.xlBottom })
{
    style.Borders[borderIndex].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
}
```