# Trouble translating border information from cell to custom style

Tags: excel, vba

SOLVED BELOW

I've been programming a workbook to load a bunch of custom cell styles based on cell information i've entered in a ListObject table, like so:
[image: Table]

Each cell has a unique configuration of formats and the hope is when i need to add more i'll just expand the list. The code I've created can handle reading the particulars of each individual cell, until it comes to the `Borders` section, then it appears to either not read it at all, or make up it's own definitions of what the Border style should be. Here's my code (sorry it's a bit long):

```
Dim lstStle As ListObject
Dim obj_wbk As Object

For Each obj_wbk In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
    If obj_wbk.Name <> "Normal" Then
        obj_wbk.Delete
    End If
Next obj_wbk
Set obj_wbk = Nothing

Set lstStle = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
For Each obj_wbk In lstStle.DataBodyRange
    If obj_wbk.Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add Name:=obj_wbk.Value2
        With ActiveWorkbook.Styles(obj_wbk.Value2)
'!!!!!!!!!!!Number properties
            .IncludeNumber = True
            .NumberFormat = obj_wbk.NumberFormat
'!!!!!!!!!!!Alignment properties
            .IncludeAlignment = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = obj_wbk.HorizontalAlignment
            .IndentLevel = obj_wbk.IndentLevel
            .Orientation = obj_wbk.Orientation
            .ReadingOrder = obj_wbk.ReadingOrder
            .ShrinkToFit = obj_wbk.ShrinkToFit
            .VerticalAlignment = obj_wbk.VerticalAlignment
            .WrapText = obj_wbk.WrapText
'!!!!!!!!!!!Font properties
            .IncludeFont = True
            .Font.Bold = obj_wbk.Font.Bold
            .Font.Color = obj_wbk.Font.Color
            .Font.Italic = obj_wbk.Font.Italic
            .Font.Name = obj_wbk.Font.Name
            .Font.Size = obj_wbk.Font.Size
            .Font.Strikethrough = obj_wbk.Font.Strikethrough
            .Font.Subscript = obj_wbk.Font.Subscript
            .Font.Superscript = obj_wbk.Font.Superscript
            .Font.Underline = obj_wbk.Font.Underline
'!!!!!!!!!!!Borders properties
            .IncludeBorder = True
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = obj_wbk.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight
'!!!!!!!!!!!Patterns/Interiors properties
            .IncludePatterns = True
            .Interior.Color = obj_wbk.Interior.Color
            .Interior.Pattern = obj_wbk.Interior.Pattern
            .Interior.PatternColor = obj_wbk.Interior.PatternColor
'!!!!!!!!!!!Protection properties
            .IncludeProtection = False
        End With
    End If
Next obj_wbk
```

Like I said, everything else gets read and pushed into the newly created style, except the `Borders`. Have I missed something?

UPDATE: When trying to break down this process further, I've uncovered that when I am trying to define a `.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)` property, it will accept the definition but immediately forget/change the value of said property in the next line. For example, `.Color` values may spontaneously change to 0 after assigning a non-zero number, or `.LineStyle` may spontaneously change to -4142. After that, any following `.Borders(...)` property gets nulled. I feel like this is a bug. Retrieving border item properties from a given cell seems to work, but assigning border segment properties to a custom cell style does not. Any further insight would be appreciated.

SOLVED: I figured out a solution from finding a VSTO question with similar issues:
[Excel range Style: specifying Borders via VSTO doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827369/excel-range-style-specifying-borders-via-vsto-doesnt-work)

By replacing `(xlEdge...)` with non-Edge enumerations (i.e. changing `Borders(xlEdgeLeft)` to `Borders(xlLeft)`), it completely solved the issues I've been having. In my opinion, the Microsoft definition of a Border Object needs to be elaborated to include xlLeft, xlRight, xlTop, and xlBottom enumerations as an Index option.
[Border Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838428.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing (xlEdge...) with non-Edge enumerations (i.e. changing Borders(xlEdgeLeft) to Borders(xlLeft)), it completely solved the issues I've been having. In my opinion, the Microsoft definition of a Border Object needs to be elaborated to include xlLeft, xlRight, xlTop, and xlBottom enumerations as an Index option. Border Object (Excel)